# Orion Context Broker already running error

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I have a problem when i start orion context broker as a docker container, it is always exiting, it says that Orion is already running, how can i fix this issue?

```
srdjan-orion-1         | time=2022-07-27T09:53:34.508Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=contextBroker.cpp[432]:pidFile | msg=PID-file '/tmp/contextBroker.pid' found. A broker seems to be running already
srdjan-orion-1 exited with code 1
```

When i run `sudo ps aux | grep contextBroker` this is the result: `srdjan     31012  0.0  0.0  11568   652 pts/0    S+   11:56   0:00 grep --color=auto contextBroker` 
The problem is also when i execute this command, the first number that appears after my username is always changing, and when i try to execute the kill order this is the result: `sudo  kill 31012 kill: (31012): No such process` 
and also this: `sudo  kill 11568 kill: (11568): No such process` 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Solved! Just used the old fashioned  sudo docker container prune and sudo docker network prune, and started containers from the beginning.